# CANopen Protocols

Tags: can

I have a [CANopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen) slave stack. Is it possible to implement both the CANopen master and slave functionalities using the same stack? Or is a separate master stack required?

Comment: Whether it is "separate" or not is merely a matter of software architecture and semantics.

Answer (score 2):

In CAN and CANopen, technically any node on the bus can be a server, a client, or both.  Code-wise, I don't see a reason why one stack couldn't handle both the server and client duties.  But if I understand your question, you are not writing the stack yourself, and you are merely using someone else's; it is provided as "slave only" and perhaps it has been implemented to only send TPDOs in an event-driven mode (other than the objects that your device's respective standard requires)?

If so, then I don't see how you can use it to make your device act as a master and just ask any node on the network for specific object data.  If not, then I would definitely try to make your stack enable your device to act as a master and a slave, because I'm not aware of any technical hurdles that would prevent this.  Hopefully I haven't misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes your understanding of the question is correct.I would like to know, how many object dictionaries are required for a CANOpen master to communicate with 'n' devices?

Comment: You'll need to download the respective specs from the CiA, e.g. DS402 for motion control, DS401 for I/O, etc.